# Why doesn't "Attach to Process" allow other transport types? VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, remote-debugging

A co-worker [posted this on an MS forum but was not able to get an answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/fd98ffb1-f864-4873-b260-2ef7297f991b).

He's using Win7, VS 2008 (C++) pro - not the express version.

When he selects Tools->Attach to Process the dlg box with the dropdown for "Transport" shows only "default" and the Qualifier field is greyed out and only shows his machine name.

He wants to debug a process on another machine.

What could be the cause for this?  Is there a service that has to be running on this dev machine for those items to be allowed.

He is running VS as an admin.

For contrast, my dropdown options for "Transport" are:

- Default
- Smart Device
- Remote (Native only with no authentication)

And the qualifier field for me is NOT greyed out.

Any comments, suggestions or ideas about why this doesn't work as expected and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your co-worker has VS 2008 Pro and not Standard?  Standard doesn't support remote debugging.

Comment: I will check that - but I am pretty sure he is using pro.

Comment: Well, he claimed to have it, and had pro on a different machine.  For some reason that machine did just have standard.  Thanks